# Query on git archive for a specific branch

Tags: git

When I tried to do a git archive on a file from a remote location for a different branch other than head/master, I do get a warning telling that

```
remote: warning: refname 'xxx' is ambiguous.
```

The command that I used was

```
git archive --remote=gitserve:some_repo xxx filename | tar -x
remote: warning: refname 'xxx' is ambiguous.
```

But when I give `xxx` as `master` or `HEAD` it works fine. But if it's some branch name I get a warning though the output is there. Let me know if there are some things that I am missing or if there is some issue in my setup.

thanks-
Shar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning about the ambigious refname tells you that “xxx” is ambigious (who’d have thought that). This means that you have a branch and a tag sharing the same name, or maybe a branch has a name that can be mistaken for a commit ID. Try using “refs/heads/*branch*” or “refs/tags/*tag*” as refname.

Comment: Thanks Bombe .. That worked by explicitly referring the branch as refs/heads/branch

Comment: You should, however, name your branches and tags less ambigiously to prevent similar problems in the future.